# How to work on diffing result generated by bindiff

Tags: ida, idapython, bin-diffing, tool-bindiff

I am new to reverse engineering, How to work on the diffing results(Similar function) generated by Bindiff using IDAPython.

*work is like finding no basic blocks, no of edges

Answer (score 1):

When you use [bindiff](https://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) e.g.,
`bindiff original.BinExport patched.BinExport`
it will create a `BinDiff` file, e.g., `original_vs_patched.BinDiff`. In the current version (6) that file is an `sqlite3` database. You can find some of the information you're looking for in the tables in that database-- specifically, the `functions` table contains the number of basic blocks and edges.

Since you're using IDA, I also recommend you check out [ida_haru](https://github.com/TakahiroHaruyama/ida_haru/blob/master/bindiff/bindiff.py), it may also export some of the information you're looking for.